# Docker build from git with optional parametrized branch

Tags: docker

I'm trying to set up a Dockerfile that, among other things, checks out some code in order to be built. Wanting to keep things flexible, the script calling the build can sometime pass a branch name (tag) or not.

```
GIT_TAG=1.0.0
docker build ... --build-arg GIT_TAG="$GIT_TAG" ...
```

Inside Dockerfile:

```
...
ARG GIT_TAG
...
RUN if [ "$GIT_TAG"!="" ] ; \
then git clone --branch ${GIT_TAG} https://github/repo/${PROJECT}.git . ; \
else git clone https://github/repo/${PROJECT}.git . ; \
fi
```

However, somehow the 'git clone' command returns an error code of 128 during build process. The same command runs fine from a bash terminal.

A stripped down version of the if statement runs fine:

```
RUN if [ "$GIT_TAG" != "" ] ; then set A="--branch ${GIT_USER}" . ; else set A="" ; fi
```

However, I cannot pass that new environment variable further down to a git clone command.

I also tried passing a full argument to docker build, such as: `--build-arg BRANCH_PARAM="--branch $GIT_TAG"` but apparently the build doesn't like quotes.

I know that I can set up an .sh script that gets called from outside the Dockerfile, but I would like to avoid that. Is there any way to either:

- pass a full string parameter as a build argument or
- conditionally add a parameter inside a RUN statement
  ?

Comment: My recommendation would be to add the Dockerfile to the repository, and have it build whatever branch is currently checked out on the host.  That would mean not running `git` commands in a Dockerfile; it would also mean not needing to figure out how to securely git credentials into the Docker build environment without leaking them into the final image, and it would let you build a test image from code you haven't committed or pushed yet.

Comment: That was the first idea, but I want to have a Dockerfile for several projects, >10, that have the same setup. Thus, would like to avoid having to copy/paste the contents or patch it over several projects when there's a change.